# Transform stiff systems to non-stiff

Tags: dynamical-systems

Many dynamic systems tend to be stiff, so an explicit integrator is unstable. The solution is to use an implicit integration scheme. I am curious if there is some way to change the dynamics of the system, preserving its characteristics and transform it into non-stiff system.

Thanks